# Angular 2~6: What is the most efficient way to communicate with "Components"?

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular6, data-sharing

These are the only methods I know so far:

- @Input/@Output | This is to communicate a child with its parent and vice versa
- @ViewChild | This is to communicate with the child component
- @Injectable Service | share data with any component
- rxjs/behaviorsubject | Share data with any component

I also saw an @Injectable component example, but I am not sure if that is also a way to share component data or not.

Ok, so I hope that the above text is clear enough so that everyone can understand where I am going. I need the most efficient and cleanest way(s) to share component variables and methods with any component without having to make a big mess and see performance drop.

I am thinking to share data using the following way, but I am not sure if this is efficient when having multiple components:

PARENT

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
class ParentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    public instance: ParentComponent;
    @ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent;

    constructor() {
        this.instance = this;
    }

    doSomethingWithParentMethod(strData: string) {
        console.log('parent data: ' + strData);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.childComponent.doSomethingMethod('pass data to child in string type');
    }
}
```

And in the Parent HTMl file:

```
<app-child [parent]="instance"></app-child>
```

CHILD

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
class ChildComponent {
    @Input() parent;

    public function doSomethingMethod(strData: string) {
        console.log('child data: ' + strData);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable Service | share data with any component
```

and it changes as per requirement , but for generic service is mainly for data transfer

Comment: I want to use a method from other component when clicking a parent html button element. I know that this can be achieved with (click)="{{fireMethod()}}", but inside the parent method, I want to be able to fire a child method and vice versa.